# VS Code ignores quote settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, single-quotes

I've a project with `.vue` and `.js` files. In my `.vue` files, all quotes I type stay single quotes. But in my `.js` files, even if I type a singlequote (`'`), it becomes a double quote.

Here, you can see my `settings.json`-file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out: The `.editorconfig` file overrides the `settings.json` file. So I had to add to the `.editorconfig` file the following line:

```
quote_type = single
```

Comment: You shouldn't have too many different files working for the same thing. Instead, modify the standard 'prettifier'!